# Error as follow when using 'import bs4', or 'from bs4 import BeautifulSoup'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Output Error as follow when using `import bs4`, or `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

```
'''Here there is output of another py file I have removed'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bs4.element import ( 
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 160, in <module> 
    workbook.close()
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 240, in close
    self._store_workbook()
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 448, in _store_workbook
    allowZip64=self.allow_zip64)
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda2\lib\zipfile.py", line 756, in __init__
    self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'D:\\Data\\\xe6\x95\xb00\xe6\x8d\xae\xe6\xba\x90.xlsx'
```

Comment: Why is there a `workbook.close()` call in `site-packages\bs4\element.py`? That is **not** an expected line in that module. Did you accidentally replace that file with one of your own?

Comment: Thank you, it works. I just doubt how it happens when I do nothing.

Comment: But you did do *something*. You managed to overwrite the file *somehow*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have corrupted your BeautifulSoup installation:

```
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 160, in <module> 
    workbook.close()
```

That is **not** BeautifulSoup code; see the [actual `bs4.element` source code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L153).

You appear to have replaced the regular `element.py` file in that package with one that writes an Excel worksheet (using the `xlsxwriter` package). You'll have to remove the whole `bs4` directory and reinstall BeautifulSoup.